# How to run Ubuntu from Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I'm going to run Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, I've installed Ubuntu from USB drive, but at the end of installation, Ubuntu prompted me to reboot system so I did it. Unexpectedly after rebooting, I can't enter Ubuntu system, automatically it moves me to Windows Boot Manager. How can I fix it? I mean certainly, how I can enter Ubuntu and next use GRUB to select OS.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: I pasted logs here: pastebin.com/6zTNikGp